# Wierd behavior of Vuex in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, axios, vuex

I have faced weird issues working VueJS recently.  I am using Vuex and Axios  and started noticing that promises are not handled correctly(only from the second call). Initially I was thinking it was related to my code, but when I ran the same code in Firefox I had no issues.

I am using latest Chrome and Vue dev tools 5.1.1

For example this code

```
registerUser({commit}, user) {
            const form = new URLSearchParams();
            form.append('login', user.login);
            form.append('password', user.password);
            form.append('email', user.email);
            form.append('firstName', user.firstName);
            form.append('lastName', user.lastName);
            form.append('roles', user.roles);

            return Axios.post(userUrl + '/create', form, config)
                .then(
                    (response) => {
                        commit('setUser', response.data);
                        commit('setErrorMessage', '');
                        if (response.status === 206) {
                            commit('setErrorMessage', response.data);
                        }
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        commit('setErrorMessage', error.response.data);
                    });

        },
```

I can see the rest call but , the promise is not handled at all.

Here I dispatch it from component and then handle result

```
this.$store.dispatch('registerUser', this.user).then(() => {
                    this.errorMessage = this.getError;
                    if (this.errorMessage.length) {
                        this.errorOccurred = true;
                    } else {
                        this.showVerify = true;
                        this.user = {
                            login: '',
                            password: '',
                            email: '',
                            firstName: '',
                            lastName: '',
                            roles: ''
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: _"noticing that promises are not handled correctly"_  could you please explain in detail what this means?

Comment: sharing some code would be helpful :)

Comment: @SMAKSS you can check the code above

Comment: @AlexBondar correct me if I'm wrong, in Axios promise base approach you should catch errors like this:
`.catch((error)=>{
commit('setErrorMessage', error.response.data);
})`
if think your problem is reside here.

Comment: @SMAKSS But my approach should also work. Anyway I need to try out